# Using var in functions with multiple loops?

Tags: javascript, var, let

Quoting from the book [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/9781491952016/)

> Unlike variables declared with `let`, it is legal to declare the same variable multiple times with `var`. And because `var` variables have function scope instead of block scope, it is actually common to do this kind of redeclaration. The variable `i` is frequently used for integer values, and especially as the index variable of for loops. In a function with multiple for loops, it is typical for each one to begin `for(var i = 0;` .... Because `var` does not scope these variables to the loop body, each of these loops is (harmlessly) re-declaring and re-initializing the same variable.

I am unable to understand what is meant in this paragraph. First I assumed the following would not have worked with second loop not iterating, because `i` would be function scoped:

```js
(function foo() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        console.log(i);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        console.log(i);
    }
})();
```

but it prints

```
0
1
0
1
```

Then I assumed this would have printed `0 0 1 1 0 1`, which is also not the case:

```js
(function foo() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
})();
```

Can someone help me understand what is meant by

> in a function of multiple for loops, `var` can be used harmlessly in each loop

and how it is different to `let`?

To me it looks like the opposite it true (which is also very confusing) where `let` can be used harmlessly in functions with multiple loops:

```js
(function foo() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
})();
```

prints:

```
0
0
1
1
0
1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`let` variables are forbidden to be re-declared *in the same scope*, like the following:

```js
let foo = 10;
let foo = 20;
```

`var` variables can be, though:

```js
var foo = 10;
var foo = 20;
console.log('ok');
```

In your first snippet, variables declared with `let` in the header of a `for` loop only exist inside the loop; they're block scoped, and aren't scoped to the outer block or function:

```js
(function foo() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        // console.log(i);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        // console.log(i);
    }
    // doesn't exist out here:
    console.log(i);
})();
```

The `let i`s above create `i`s in *two different* scopes, which is why it's not forbidden. Similarly:

```js
(function foo() {
    {
        let i = 10;
    }
    {
        let i = 20;
    }
    console.log('OK up until here');
    // doesn't exist out here:
    console.log(i);
})();
```

`var`s, in contrast, have function scope, not block scope - with your `var` version of the loop, since there's only one function, this:

```
(function foo() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
})();
```

is equivalent to

```
(function foo() {
    var i; // the `i` variable exists at this level
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
})();
```

> Then I assumed this would have printed 0 0 1 1 0 1, which is also not the case:

`i` gets initialized to zero at the beginning of each loop.

The first loop begins once, at the start of the function.

The second loop begins just after logging `i`, on each iteration of the outer loop.

```
(function foo() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
})();
```

- outer loop initialization: 0 is assigned to i
- 0 gets logged
- inner loop initialization: 0 is assigned to i
- 0 gets logged
- inner loop increments i to 1 and starts again
- inner loop: 1 gets logged
- inner loop increments i to 2 and breaks, since i < 2 is no longer fulfilled
- outer loop increments i to 3 and breaks, since i < 2 is no longer fulfilled

So you get `0 0 1` logged.

What the article probably means by

> in a function of multiple for loops, var can be used harmlessly in each loop

is that it can work if both loops are on the *same level* of the function, eg

```
for (...) {
}
for (...) {
}
```

It *definitely won't* work with nested loops, if both loops use the same variable, because there's only ever a single `i` variable, rather than one for each loop.

> where let can be used harmlessly in functions with multiple loops:

For nested loops, yes, since variables declared with `let` are unique to each loop, rather than being shared across the whole containing function.

Comment: I guess it is just a paragraph that not much attention was paid at.. I understand all this, I do not understand how `var` is harmless compared to `let`. Thank you very much for your time and your explanation.

Comment: Nested for loops is just one pitfall of `var`. Another would be if you define a function inside a for loop, that uses the `i` variable, and doesn't get called until after the loop finishes, if the `i` variable was declared with `var`, it'll use the last value of `i` instead of the value that `i` was at the time the function was created. I'm not sure why the author called it harmless ... there's a lot of pitfalls with `var`.

Comment: Yeah, personally I'd consider `var` completely obsolete, it has too many problems. Easier to just never use it.